# Run jQuery function on drop down change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a jQuery function that currently runs on Click Event.  I need to change it so that it runs when a drop down box (Select- Option) value is changed.  Here is my code:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label>
    <select name="otherCatches" id="otherCatches">
      <option value="*">All</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</form>
```

---

```
$("#otherCatches").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "otherCatchesMap.php>",
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#results").html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I know these kind of comments are frowned upon, but nevertheless: Googling for `jquery change` would have given you the link to the `change()` function as first hit: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `change()` instead of `click()`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#otherCatches").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
     url: "otherCatchesMap.php>",
     success: function(msg){
       $("#results").html(msg);
     }
   });
  });
});
```

Comment: .change() is great for <select> lists

Answer (score 23):

http://api.jquery.com/change/

```
$(function() {
    $("#otherCatches").change(function() {
       $(this).val() // how to get the value of the selected item if you need it
    });
});
```

Answer (score 12):

```
$("#otherCatches").change(function () {
    //// Your code        
});
```