# jquery function fired when dropdownlist selectedvalue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, function, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I have a jQuery animate function which I want to call if the selectedvalue for my dropdown list is X

```
       <script>
    $(function () {
        var state = true;
        ($("#button").click)(function () {
            if (state) {
                $("#effect").animate({
                    backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
                    color: "#fff",
                    width: 500
                }, 1000);
                  } else {
                $("#effect").animate({
                    backgroundColor: "#fff",
                    color: "#000",
                    width:500

                }, 1000);
            }
            state = !state;
        });
    });
```

Comment: There are a lot of formatting issues here, as well this looks like a `.click` event not a `.change()` one for a dropdown list like you're saying you want.

Comment: I do agree that the event should be written on dropwn list rather than button

Comment: here is an example which may help your<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910795/run-jquery-function-on-drop-down-change

Answer (score 0):

Your can try like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var state = true;
  $("#otherCatches").change(function() {
      if (state) {
            $("#effect").animate({
                backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
                color: "#fff",
                width: 500
            }, 1000);
              } else {
            $("#effect").animate({
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                color: "#000",
                width:500

            }, 1000);
        }
        state = !state;

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

DropDown id -> ddlDropDown

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
          var state = true;
        $("#ddlDropDown").change(function() {
             if ($("#ddlDropDown").val()=="X") { //Checking if value is X
                $("#effect").animate({
                     backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
                     color: "#fff",
                     width: 500
                  }, 1000);
              } else {
               $("#effect").animate({
               backgroundColor: "#fff",
               color: "#000",
               width:500

        }, 1000);
      }
      state = !state;
  });
});
```